# Bitcoin core RPC method "sendfrom" is not working

Tags: ruby

Bitcoin core RPC method "sendfrom" is not working from my controller.I am running the following command from my controller

```
bitcoin_cli = BitcoinCli.new  
response = bitcoin_cli.execute_function("sendfrom", "#{account.strip}", "#{address.strip}", "#{amount}")
```

and here is execute function

```
class BitcoinCli   

  def initialize()

  end


  def execute_function(function_name, *params)  
    result = %x{/usr/local/bin/bitcoin-cli #{function_name} #{params.join(' ')}}  
  end
```

end

but after executing the function the response is nil.

Comment: Are you sure that the command `bitcoin-cli` outputs its result to `STDOUT`?

Comment: it does not create any output.